# How to return a List<> containing the most recent item in a List<> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have the following list of tuples:

```
var allXmlUsers = new List<(string login, string email, string createdOn)>();
allXmlUsers.Add(("thompson", "sdfsd@dkfjdkf.com", "2015-03-04 20:32:04"));
allXmlUsers.Add(("dupont", "asdfdfd@dkfjdkf.com", "2017-03-04 20:32:04"));
allXmlUsers.Add(("james", "dfsdfs33@dkfjdkf.com", "2016-03-04 20:32:04"));
```

I want to replace it with a `List<>` that only has the most recent item, e.g. "dupont".

I can return a single tuple object like this:

```
var single = (from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

And I return a `List<>` that is reordered like this:

```
var list = from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x;
```

But how do I return a `List<>` containing only one tuple, namely the most recent, something like this?

```
//allXmlUsers = ((from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
//(error: cannot resolve symbol to List)
```

Comment: You need to create a new empty list and add `single` to it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am assuming the OP wants to avoid that syntax as it's not as compact and is a bit long winded IMO.

Comment: Do you really want a `List<T>` or maybe just an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Take` method to only take 1 element from the enumerable

```
var single = (from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x)
             .Take(1)
             .ToList();
```

**Edit**

The snippet above will return an empty list (one of length 0), this might be the desired behavior, but you might also want to return a list containing a single `null` value instead. If so you can use the `DefaultIfEmpty` method

```
var single = (from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x)
             .Take(1)
             .DefaultIfEmpty()
             .ToList();
```

Comment: This might not matter at all depending on what the OP wants but this will return an empty list of `allXmlUsers` is empty whereas with `FirstOrDefault` the list will always have one element in it.

Comment: @Aominè Good point, it depends what behavior he wants on empty list, I will add a note of this for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

if this is an operation which you use quite often then another option would be to create a `ToSingletonList` extension method as follows:

```
public static class Extensions
{  
     /// <summary>
     /// Returns the first element of the sequence in a list or a default value in a list if the sequence contains no elements.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="source">The IEnumerable<T> to return the first element of.</param>
     /// <returns>default in a list if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in source in a list.</returns>

    public static List<T> ToSingletonList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => 
               new List<T> { source.FirstOrDefault() };
}
```

Then in your case you'd do:

```
var single = (from x in allXmlUsers orderby x.createdOn descending select x).ToSingletonList();
```